# Seek Admission(s) To or In or Of?

Tags: prepositions

Which words are the most appropriate: He seeks admission (or admissions) to (or in or of) the graduate program at XYZ University?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the correct preposition is "to" as far as standard English is concerned. We often hear "gain admission into"in spoken English but this is non-standard.
Thank you.

Comment: https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/admit+into

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the previous answer. The correct preposition for "admission" meaning to enter into, is "to". An example is "He was admitted to hospital". One does not say, "into hospital".

For "admission" meaning issuing a statement, albeit reluctantly, or confessing, the correct preposition is "of" - e.g."He made an admission of (*what?*) guilt".

Using the verb form of "admission", which is "to admit", we use "to"- e.g. "he admitted to his guilt".

"In" is incorrect in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

*He seeks admission ***to***/***into*** the graduate program at XYZ University.*

[***admit (someone or something) into (something or some place)***](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/admit+into)

To allow someone to enter or become a member of some organization or place.

*That university only admits the best applicants into its law program.*

*This school does not admit students into a degree program without a high school diploma.*

***[admit (someone) to (something or some place)](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/admit)***

To allow someone to enter or become a member of some organization or place.

*This ticket will admit you to the art exhibit.*

*We were admitted to the club after we showed the security guard our identification.*

*No, you don't have to pay—my membership will admit us both to the botanical garden.*

Source: [idioms.thefreedictionary.com](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/admit)

****[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=admitted+to+the+program%2Cadmitted+into+the+program%2Cadmission+to+the+program%2Cadmission+into+the+program&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=3)****